# how to draw Highcharts by php

Tags: php, sql-server, highcharts, linechart

I am using highcharts and microsoft sql server database.I want to draw line charts by database and select xasis and yasis from database.
So when i try on the localhost, it gives empty page.What is its problem?Why does it give empty page?I dont understand.
In fact, i dont know how write code that select to xasis and yasis from database.

```
        xAxis: {
        categories: ['
        <?php 
        $tsql = "SELECT  FROM statistik where mpid=1 ";
        $result=sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
        while( $registros = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result)) 
        {
        ?>
         '<?php echo $registros["24hMW"] ?>',

         <?php
        }
        ?>

        ']
    },
```

Comment: I advice you to check out manual: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database

Answer (score 1):

> **Highcharts** runs on the client side only and is completely ignorant of how your server is set up. This means that if your server is
>   running PHP and MySQL, or **any other type of server technology coupled
>   with any SQL engine**(includes SQL-Server), you can dynamically produce the HTML and
>   JavaScript required by Highcharts.

The most basic way, just add some PHP code within your parent HTML page that handles the data from the chart. Below is a basic, low-level example of how to pull data from an SQL-Server table and add it to your chart.

Say you have a DateTime x-axis and irregular intervals between the points. Then you can't use the pointInterval approach, but you need to get the date time for each point. It should look like this:

```
<?php
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
   extract $row;
   $datetime *= 1000; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
   $data[] = "[$datetime, $value]";
}
?>
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container'
      },
      series: [{
         data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
      }]
});
```

Please refer this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RenjithVR4/mc2m76t4/).